# Not able to populate jstree table

Tags: javascript, jstree, treetable

I am working or tree table to show drilldown type or tree type structure. I have json with me and want to populate that to a tree table

But here I am getting error as `TypeError: $(...).jstree is not a function`

Am I missing any plugin or anything? From my side I have included all the plugins but same error I am getting.

```js
var data;
 data = [
   {
     "data": {
       "totalAmount": "1394334",
       "itemcode": "10598"
     },
     "children": [
       {
         "data": {
           "totalAmount": "987579",
           "itemcode": "7545"
         },
         "children": [
           {
             "data": {
               "totalAmount": "476426",
               "itemcode": "3747"
             },
             "children": [
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "49644",
                   "itemcode": "29"
                 },
                 "text": "North Indian"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "194495",
                   "itemcode": "474"
                 },
                 "text": "South Indian-1-Flr"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "80768",
                   "itemcode": "842"
                 },
                 "text": "Take-away counter 1"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "60878",
                   "itemcode": "1918"
                 },
                 "text": "Coffee Counter"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "81999",
                   "itemcode": "434"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade Pos1"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "8642",
                   "itemcode": "50"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade Pos 2"
               }
             ],
             "text": "2018-09-01"
           },
           {
             "data": {
               "totalAmount": "511153",
               "itemcode": "3798"
             },
             "children": [
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "39",
                   "itemcode": "1"
                 },
                 "text": "North Indian"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "118647",
                   "itemcode": "334"
                 },
                 "text": "South Indian-1-Flr"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "119871",
                   "itemcode": "137"
                 },
                 "text": "South Indian-2-Flr"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "109527",
                   "itemcode": "901"
                 },
                 "text": "Take-away counter 1"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "64771",
                   "itemcode": "1896"
                 },
                 "text": "Coffee Counter"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "78037",
                   "itemcode": "464"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade Pos1"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "20261",
                   "itemcode": "65"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade Pos 2"
               }
             ],
             "text": "2018-09-02"
           }
         ],
         "text": "JAYANAGAR"
       },
       {
         "data": {
           "totalAmount": "207845",
           "itemcode": "2299"
         },
         "children": [
           {
             "data": {
               "totalAmount": "92141",
               "itemcode": "1066"
             },
             "children": [
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "53822",
                   "itemcode": "242"
                 },
                 "text": "Restaurant"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "15339",
                   "itemcode": "660"
                 },
                 "text": "Coffee Counter"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "7548",
                   "itemcode": "33"
                 },
                 "text": "Takeaway"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "15432",
                   "itemcode": "131"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade POS"
               }
             ],
             "text": "2018-09-01"
           },
           {
             "data": {
               "totalAmount": "115704",
               "itemcode": "1233"
             },
             "children": [
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "69946",
                   "itemcode": "278"
                 },
                 "text": "Restaurant"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "18197",
                   "itemcode": "743"
                 },
                 "text": "Coffee Counter"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "8741",
                   "itemcode": "42"
                 },
                 "text": "Takeaway"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "18820",
                   "itemcode": "170"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade POS"
               }
             ],
             "text": "2018-09-02"
           }
         ],
         "text": "MALLESHWARAM"
       },
       {
         "data": {
           "totalAmount": "198910",
           "itemcode": "754"
         },
         "children": [
           {
             "data": {
               "totalAmount": "115313",
               "itemcode": "397"
             },
             "children": [
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "107602",
                   "itemcode": "355"
                 },
                 "text": "Restaurant"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "7711",
                   "itemcode": "42"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade POS"
               }
             ],
             "text": "2018-09-01"
           },
           {
             "data": {
               "totalAmount": "83597",
               "itemcode": "357"
             },
             "children": [
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "78537",
                   "itemcode": "319"
                 },
                 "text": "Restaurant"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "5060",
                   "itemcode": "38"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade POS"
               }
             ],
             "text": "2018-09-02"
           }
         ],
         "text": "KOLAR"
       }
     ],
     "text": ""
   }
 ]

 // load jstree
 $("#jstree").jstree({
   plugins: ["grid","dnd","contextmenu","sort"],
   core: {
     data: data
   }, 
   // configure tree table
   grid: {
           columns: [
             {width: 'auto', header: "Outlet"},
             
             {width: 'auto', value: "itemcode", header: "NoOfBills", cellClass: "aright"},
        
             {width: 'auto', value: "totalAmount", header: "Amount", cellClass: "aright"}
             
           ],
     resizable: true,
     
 
  
   }
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-treetable/3.2.0/jquery.treetable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<div id="jstree"></div>
```

I have edited my snippet; it is almost working fine but it is not showing columns like I have in my json `outlet`,`noofbills`,`amount`.

Comment: FYI it looks like you have mixed tabs and spaces in your indentation, which should be avoided: you may want to replace those tab characters with two spaces each (which looks to be your actual main indentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `jstreegrid.min.js`.

Following tag need to add in your code and it will work.

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstreegrid/3.9.5/jstreegrid.min.js"></script>`

```js
var data;
 data = [
   {
     "data": {
       "totalAmount": "1394334",
       "itemcode": "10598"
     },
     "children": [
       {
         "data": {
           "totalAmount": "987579",
           "itemcode": "7545"
         },
         "children": [
           {
             "data": {
               "totalAmount": "476426",
               "itemcode": "3747"
             },
             "children": [
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "49644",
                   "itemcode": "29"
                 },
                 "text": "North Indian"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "194495",
                   "itemcode": "474"
                 },
                 "text": "South Indian-1-Flr"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "80768",
                   "itemcode": "842"
                 },
                 "text": "Take-away counter 1"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "60878",
                   "itemcode": "1918"
                 },
                 "text": "Coffee Counter"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "81999",
                   "itemcode": "434"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade Pos1"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "8642",
                   "itemcode": "50"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade Pos 2"
               }
             ],
             "text": "2018-09-01"
           },
           {
             "data": {
               "totalAmount": "511153",
               "itemcode": "3798"
             },
             "children": [
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "39",
                   "itemcode": "1"
                 },
                 "text": "North Indian"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "118647",
                   "itemcode": "334"
                 },
                 "text": "South Indian-1-Flr"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "119871",
                   "itemcode": "137"
                 },
                 "text": "South Indian-2-Flr"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "109527",
                   "itemcode": "901"
                 },
                 "text": "Take-away counter 1"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "64771",
                   "itemcode": "1896"
                 },
                 "text": "Coffee Counter"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "78037",
                   "itemcode": "464"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade Pos1"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "20261",
                   "itemcode": "65"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade Pos 2"
               }
             ],
             "text": "2018-09-02"
           }
         ],
         "text": "JAYANAGAR"
       },
       {
         "data": {
           "totalAmount": "207845",
           "itemcode": "2299"
         },
         "children": [
           {
             "data": {
               "totalAmount": "92141",
               "itemcode": "1066"
             },
             "children": [
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "53822",
                   "itemcode": "242"
                 },
                 "text": "Restaurant"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "15339",
                   "itemcode": "660"
                 },
                 "text": "Coffee Counter"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "7548",
                   "itemcode": "33"
                 },
                 "text": "Takeaway"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "15432",
                   "itemcode": "131"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade POS"
               }
             ],
             "text": "2018-09-01"
           },
           {
             "data": {
               "totalAmount": "115704",
               "itemcode": "1233"
             },
             "children": [
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "69946",
                   "itemcode": "278"
                 },
                 "text": "Restaurant"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "18197",
                   "itemcode": "743"
                 },
                 "text": "Coffee Counter"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "8741",
                   "itemcode": "42"
                 },
                 "text": "Takeaway"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "18820",
                   "itemcode": "170"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade POS"
               }
             ],
             "text": "2018-09-02"
           }
         ],
         "text": "MALLESHWARAM"
       },
       {
         "data": {
           "totalAmount": "198910",
           "itemcode": "754"
         },
         "children": [
           {
             "data": {
               "totalAmount": "115313",
               "itemcode": "397"
             },
             "children": [
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "107602",
                   "itemcode": "355"
                 },
                 "text": "Restaurant"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "7711",
                   "itemcode": "42"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade POS"
               }
             ],
             "text": "2018-09-01"
           },
           {
             "data": {
               "totalAmount": "83597",
               "itemcode": "357"
             },
             "children": [
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "78537",
                   "itemcode": "319"
                 },
                 "text": "Restaurant"
               },
               {
                 "data": {
                   "totalAmount": "5060",
                   "itemcode": "38"
                 },
                 "text": "Trade POS"
               }
             ],
             "text": "2018-09-02"
           }
         ],
         "text": "KOLAR"
       }
     ],
     "text": ""
   }
 ]

 // load jstree
 $("#jstree").jstree({
   plugins: ["grid","dnd","contextmenu","sort"],
   core: {
     data: data
   }, 
   // configure tree table
   grid: {
           columns: [
             {width: 'auto', header: "Outlet"},
             
             {width: 'auto', value: "itemcode", header: "NoOfBills", cellClass: "aright"},
        
             {width: 'auto', value: "totalAmount", header: "Amount", cellClass: "aright"}
             
           ],
     resizable: true,
     
 
  
   }
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-treetable/3.2.0/jquery.treetable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstreegrid/3.9.5/jstreegrid.min.js"></script>
<div id="jstree"></div>
```

Comment: hey can you please check out this post one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521258/how-to-display-image-dynamically-on-ui  I have been stuck here for long just want some approach to achieve what I am trying to